# Laplace transform of generalized hypergeometric distribution

Tags: laplace-transform, hypergeometric-function, moment-generating-functions, cumulants

What is please the Laplace transform (moment generating function $M(t)$) of a generalised hypergeometric distribution shown below
$$p_X(x)=K\cdot\frac{(a_1)_x\dots(a_p)_x}{(b_1)_x\dots(b_q)_x}\cdot\frac{\theta^x}{x!}$$
for $\theta>0$ and some constant $K$?

Meaning $$\mathcal{L}\left\{ p_X(x)\right\} \left(s\right)=K\cdot\sum_{x\geq0}\frac{(a_1)_x\dots(a_p)_x}{(b_1)_x\dots(b_q)_x}\cdot\frac{\theta^x}{x!}e^{-xs}
 $$ In the case you would know also the cumulant generating function $K(t)=\log M(t)$, I would be most obliged.

Comment: You need an integral sign just after the equal sign in the second formula...

Comment: in the discrete case it is a sum [e.g. here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2063374/567355)

Comment: Your formulas are incomplete : you need a summation symbol Σ in your first equation and an integral sign $\int_0^{\infty}$... before summation symbol Σ in the second equation.

Comment: my first equation is meant not to be a generalised hypergeometric function, but it terms. The constant is 1/$\sum$. It is a function of x, not $\theta$

Comment: The terms are the probabilities.